# RuntimeError: PytorchStreamReader failed reading zip archive: failed finding central directory

Tags: pytorch, resnet, coremltools

When I convert a my trained pytorch model to coreml model, I got this error:

```
File "/Users/lion/Documents/MyLab/web_workspace/sky_replacement/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/jit/_serialization.py", line 161, in load
cpp_module = torch._C.import_ir_module(cu, str(f), map_location, _extra_files)

RuntimeError: PytorchStreamReader failed reading zip archive: failed finding central directory
```

This is my code:

```
from networks import *
import coremltools as ct

run_device = torch.device("cpu")
net_G = define_G(input_nc=3, output_nc=1, ngf=64, 
netG='coord_resnet50').to(run_device)
checkpoint = torch.load('./model/best_ckpt.pt', map_location=run_device)
net_G.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model_G_state_dict'])
net_G.to(run_device)
net_G.eval()

model = ct.convert('./model/best_ckpt.pt', source='pytorch', inputs=[ct.ImageType()], skip_model_load=True)
model.save("result.mlmodel")
```

Comment: did you find a solution? Do you know why the problem arises in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue because a failed git LFS smudge corrupted the checkpoint. Check the file size/checksum of your ckpt/pth file.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with the PyTorch version and saving mechanism. I had the same problem and solved it by passing the kwarg `_use_new_zipfile_serialization=False` when saving the model. More details [here](https://www.10k.cn/article/11784.html).